screensize to big after latest update aug 26 2024
Basic stats:
Dell inc 31", Resolution 3940x2160
ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
gnome 42.9
windows system x11
geforce rtx 2060
My problem : status somewhat broken system at the moment
When I login, the screen is to wide, I can scroll left and right as if the view is smaller than what should be on the screen. So either the activites ruler to the left is visible or the on/off button in the upper right is visible.
work around right now is to do a display setting-> resolution and change it back and forth until the screen and view matches again.
summary: screen to wide at login, resolution change helps to show expected result.
I have to little knowledge about the underlying problem to fix this problem, please someone more experienced could look into this.
My inexperienced guess would be that the background picture is wider then my screen resolution and that this makes the screen wider than whats possible to show. I dont know how to verify this or how to check why it happens at login and not at screen resolution changes.
UPDATE: the command xrandr gives following output:
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4864 x 2160, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 697mm x 392mm
3840x2160     60.00*+  29.98
2560x1440     59.95
2048x1280     59.96
2048x1080     24.00
1920x1200     59.88
1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    23.98
1600x1200     60.00
1600x900      60.00
1280x1024     75.02    60.02
1280x720      59.94    50.00
1152x864      75.00
1024x768      75.03    60.00
800x600       75.00    60.32
720x576       50.00
720x480       59.94
640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
None-1-1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
1024x768      60.00 +
There is a "None-1-1" a ghost screen connected that changes the view shown on the only screen available. I dont know how to remove that extra ghost screen.
